# Bootstrap col-md-x nested inside col-md-x

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I suppose it's wrong to nest a col-md-x immediately inside a col-md-x in Bootstrap 3. Am I right?

I have following at the moment:

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
  <input class="col-md-4" value="something" />
  <div class="col-md-8">Something here</div>
</div>
```

In this case, the input border starts at the very beginning of the row. It doesn't have any padding on the outside of it. 
I would like the input to show 15px away from the row border. The way I know of how to achieve this is to put this input inside a col-md-x. However, could this cause any issues?

Comment: row border? I wouldn't put a border on the `.row` element... that'll get wonky with the way the rows/cols work

Comment: What I meant is the non-visible border of it. The margin of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, just write the markup a little differently, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control" value="something" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <p class="form-control-static">Something here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem was putting the `col-md-4` class on the input.

Comment: I think I tried something similar before. Didn't use this form-control and neither form-control-static. Why use them there?

Comment: They're just the bootstrap standards. It sets the controls to 100% width (of the col-md-x container) and gives them some style. The static version sets the text to be in the same line as the input

Comment: I've ended up skipping the form-control class and instead defined a custom class in my css file with width of 100%. The style that form-control provides didn't fit my needs. I am marking this as an answer, because it directed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

From the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting):

> To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of
>   .col-sm-* columns within an existing .col-sm-* column.

So as long as you are nesting within child rows, you are gonna be fine. Another option would be custom css rules and ids for your nested structure to achieve the desired padding or margin.

**UPDATE**

To refer to your comment, since this is about validation states: let me add that bootstrap already offers great [validation-highlighting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation). See this quick sample. The bootstrap docs on forms offer great documentation on this topic. As for the padding: I like to put most of my "not-inline" forms into a `.well`, which shows the user, where action is required and allows a consistent styling of forms...

```js
var resetSec = function(){
  $('#sth-form-section').removeClass('has-error');
  $('#sth-form-section').removeClass('has-warning');
  $('#sth-form-section').removeClass('has-success');
  $('#helpBlock-sth').addClass('sr-only');
  $('#helpBlock-sth').html('');
};

$('#invalid').click(function(){
  resetSec();
  $('#sth-form-section').addClass('has-error');
  $('#helpBlock-sth').removeClass('sr-only');
  $('#helpBlock-sth').html('Oh snap! Better think about this one more time!');
});

$('#valid').click(function(){
  resetSec();
  $('#sth-form-section').addClass('has-success');
  $('#helpBlock-sth').removeClass('sr-only');
  $('#helpBlock-sth').html('Well done! I think your input was the best so far!');
});


$('#reset').click(function(){
  resetSec();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="well">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div id="sth-form-section" class="form-group">
            <label for="something" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Something:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="something" placeholder="Something here">
                <span id="helpBlock-sth" class="help-block sr-only"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="reset">Reset</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="invalid">Invalid</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="valid">Valid</button>
```

Comment: Well, yeah. But it seems a bit weird to define the same css rules which would be left padding and right padding of 15px, if they are already defined by the col.

Comment: Well, it depends. is there a relationship between the two elements? Eg. is the div a "label"/description of the input?

Comment: The div is meant to display an error in case the input is not validated. So it's an auxiliary field, which may or may not be used. But they should preferably stay on the same row.

Comment: i edited my answer. maybe this is an alternative for you